# Converting JObject to a dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, json.net

I am calling a REST endpoint from C# and I am receiving json which gets serialized into an object. One of the properties on this object is a dynamic property. The value of the dynamic property is set as a anonymous object on the server site like this:

```
myObject.MyDynamicProp = new { Id = "MyId2134", Name = "MyName" };
```

On the client site the value of the dynamic property from the json serialization is a JObject containing the following value:

```
{{
  "id": "MyId2134",
  "Name": "MyName"
}}
```

I would have expected to be able to access the properties like this:

```
var s = myObject.MyDynamicProp.Name;
```

but it does not find the Name property instead I have to get the value like this:

```
var s = myObject.MyDynamicProp["Name"].Value;
```

I tried converting the JObject into a dynamic object like this but it returns JObject:

```
var dyn = myObject.MyDynamicProp.ToObject<dynamic>();
```

How can I convert the dynamic property value such that I can call its properties directly?

```
var s = myObject.MyDynamicProp.Name;
```

UPDATE ...

I ran the following

```
 dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"MyDynamicProp\": {\"id\": \"MyId2134\", \"Name\": \"MyName\"}}");
 string name = d.MyDynamicProp.Name;
```

Which gives me the following the error:

```
 {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:    `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for `MyDynamicProp'
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ThrowInstruction.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x00027]
```

I would like to add that this is an Xamarin iOS project and the code is located in a PCL library.

---

I assumed there was a problem with my code but it looks like it is not possible to use dynamic types within a Xamarin iOS project.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/

Answer (score 30):

It is actually quite easy. Instead of using `var` use `dynamic` on your `JObject` and you will be fine:

```
dynamic do = myObject.MyDynamicProp;

string name = do.Name;
```

From your fragment:

```
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"MyDynamicProp\": {\"id\": \"MyId2134\", \"Name\": \"MyName\"}}");
string name = d.MyDynamicProp.Name;

Console.WriteLine(name); // writes MyName
```

Why this works: As [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67392/richard) explained, `JObject` derives indirectly from `JToken` which implements [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider.aspx). It is that interface that allows `dynamic` to work.

Comment: Why this works: `JObject` derives indirectly from `JToken` which implements [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider.aspx). It is that interface that allows `dynamic` to work.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks Richard. Can I append that to my answer?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but even if I use dynamic instead of var I get "Unknown member: Name" when I call the property.

Comment: It is `Name`, not `name`.

Comment: The precise exception I get is {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for `Name' ...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Please see my updated code. I also added that this is an Xamarin iOS project and the code is running within a PCL library.

Comment: Okay, that could be a reason indeed. I have no experience on that. It does seem to come a long way, so I think it should be possible.

Comment: Can you give it a try with a regular `dynamic` variable?

Answer (score 0):

create a linker.xml file inside android
and BuildAction to linkDescription

then paste the below code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="Mono.Android">
    <type fullname="Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler" preserve="all" />
  </assembly>
    
    
    <assembly fullname="mscorlib"></assembly>
        
    <assembly fullname="System.Core"></assembly> 
        <assembly fullname="System.Runtime.Serialization"> </assembly> 
    <assembly fullname="Newtonsoft.Json"></assembly>
 \
    <assembly fullname="System.Reactive.Linq"></assembly> 
    <assembly fullname="System.Reactive.Interfaces"></assembly> 
 
    <assembly fullname="System.Xml"></assembly> 
        
   <assembly fullname="Xamarin.Forms.Core"></assembly>
</linker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var expanded = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>("{ ... }");
dynamic dynamicData = expanded;
```

The reason that the Patrick Hofman's answer won't work is because some compiler magic is causing `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>` to return a JObject. I dont know why this is the case, but your `dynamic` object is actually secretly a `JObject`.  That is why the program throws a RuntimeBinderException saying that `JObject` doesn't contain the dynamic property when you try to call it with `d.MyDynamicProp`.

The solution that I presented fixes that by making sure it successfully deserializes as an `ExpandoObject` (which is what the dynamic type effectively is), then use the next line to cast the ExpandoObject into dynamic, which works.

NOTE: MY CODE IS 2 LINES FOR A REASON. THE CODE BELOW **WILL NOT WORK**

```
dynamic dynamicData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>("{ ... }");
```

This code will get 'optimized' and attempt to cast directly to a `dynamic` type, resulting in the previously mentioned error.